# Projecting rectangular stereography centred on 42°N, 10°E

Tags: coordinate-system, software-recommendations, grib-2

I have a precipitation GRIB2 file obtained at EUMETSAT H-SAF I am able to decode it to ascii but the software I am using (gdal, ArcMap,...) does not recognize the projection (in the title) so I am not able to properly project to Web Mercator for example.

So can anyone please suggest software that preferably works on Ubuntu and projects either grib2 files to other projections or is able to recognise the projection from decoded ascii.

Comment: Have you tried just an oblique stereographic projection centered on the point in question?

Comment: Yes, the problem was the definition is incomplete.ž

Answer (score 0):

The program is provided by HSAF alone and can be downloaded via FTP that they use for data distribution. The program is called grib2ascii. Instructions for compiling and usage are also provided. Basically you compile, copy the grib2 file into grib2ascii folder and run the program. I Then used python and GDAL to produce a raster which is automatically in WGS84 coordinate system.